# Meteor avoid double refreshes when third party widget changes it's own reactive datasource

Tags: javascript, meteor, dom-events, jstree

I have a jsTree which I am trying to bi-directionally "connect" to a Meteor collection. Right now I automatically trigger a `jsTree.refresh()` whenever the collection updates with the help of `.observeChanges`:

```
FileTree.find().observeChanges({
  added: function() {
    $.jstree.reference('#fileTree').refresh();
  },
  changed: function() {
    $.jstree.reference('#fileTree').refresh();
  },
  removed: function() {
    $.jstree.reference('#fileTree').refresh();
  }
});
```

I want to allow editing of the database by dragging things around in jsTree.  Here's how it would look:

1. User drags element to new location.
2. jsTree updates the location of the element in the tree.
3. jsTree calls event handler
4. Event handler updates database

My problem is, if I understand everything correctly, is that the database update would trigger the `observeChanges` event that I set up earlier.  That would cause yet another refresh of the tree.  That causes an annoying flicker which would interrupt users.  (i.e. the file browser would be unusable for about 0.75s after every drag/drop operation.)

How can I prevent this unneeded update, or is there a better way to structure my interface with jsTree that would prevent this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen this?

- https://github.com/tobkle/meteor-jstree-example
- https://github.com/tobkle/meteor-jstree

It looks like he/she is using `autorun` vs. `observeChanges` but is mostly the same concept as yours:

```
Template.showtree.rendered  = function(){

  var self  = this;
  var nodes = [];

  Nodes1  = $('#tree1').tree();
  Nodes2  = $('#tree2').tree();

  if (!self.handle){
    self.handle = Meteor.autorun(function(){
      // refresh trees on new data
      nodes = Nodes.find();
      Nodes1.tree('option', 'data', 'Projects');
      Nodes2.tree('option', 'data', 'Contexts');
    }); //self.handle
  } // if (!self.handle)
}
```

If this is something only a single user would be editing (at a time) then perhaps you simply **don't refresh** it based on DB updates, and leave the tree as an interface to author, only.

If it needs to refresh based on DB updates (from other users, or just to be in sync), you might consider changing your workflow/logic:

1. the `changed.jstree` event, updates the database locally, blocking
2. the `autorun` triggers the refresh in jstree

which should, in theory, only result in 1 refresh vs. 2 or 3

Or if you really want to limit re-draws... you could find the **old parent node** and the **new parent node** and only us `refresh_node(obj)` to refresh just those changes nodes:

> [refresh_node (obj)](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=refresh_node(obj))
>
> refreshes a node in the tree (reload its children) all opened nodes
>   inside that node are reloaded with calls to load_node.

Comment: Good point about not necessarily needing to refresh it automatically, but I really need that feature because I'm going to set something up on the server to monitor for changes to the filesystem and push it to the db which would then need to update all the clients.

Comment: What do you mean by "updates the database locally, blocking"?  Sounds like just what I need but I don't know what that means or how to do it.

Comment: I was wrong... `Collection.insert()` can block on the server, but not on the client... http://docs.meteor.com/#insert

Comment: But you still could do it blockingly, with a `Meteor.method()`... so on the `changed.jstree` event, do your collection updates inside a `Meteor.method()` without a callback (blocking) on the client... then when your `changed.jstree` event is finished, the database will already be "in sync" with the rendered version.

Comment: but wouldn't that still notify `.observeChanges` and therefore make the ui flash?  In other words, wouldn't the same thing happen, only more slowly?

Comment: Accepting as answer because it appears to not actually be an issue with jsTree, but I'm still curious exactly how to prevent double updates in general.

Comment: how did you manage to add this package to meteor , does it still exist , i can't get it to work , i tried to include the jquery plugin directly but no good